# Where is size getting it's value (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, class

Where is "int size " getting it's value from? I read code like 1000 times,but I still have no clue where is "size" initialized, I am new in java, but I don't understand this one,code is working fine any help would be nice. thanks in advance

```
public class Study {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue queue = new Queue();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
      queue.enqueue(i);

    while (!queue.empty())
      System.out.print(queue.dequeue() + " ");
  }
}

class Queue {
  private int[] elements;
  private int size;

  public Queue() {
    elements = new int[8];
  }

  public void enqueue(int value) {
    if (size >= elements.length) {
      int[] temp = new int[elements.length * 2];
      System.arraycopy(elements, 0, temp, 0, elements.length);
      System.out.println(elements.length);
      elements = temp;
    }

    elements[size++] = value;
  }

  public int dequeue() {
    int v = elements[0];

    // Shift all elements in the array left
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
      elements[i] = elements[i + 1];
    }

    size--;

    return v;
  }

  public boolean empty() {
    return size == 0;
  }

  public int getSize() {
    return size;
  }
}
```

Comment: `size++`and `size--`

Comment: yes but you need value to increase or decrease it right? I know it is not set automatically

Comment: you can find information about variable initialization on [Oracle website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: thanks that was helpful :)

Comment: *I know it is not set automatically* It is, to `0`.

Comment: `size` is automatically initalised to `0` when `Queue` is created

Comment: Initially size=0 because of default initialization in Java. Then when you enqueue, you do size++ which increases size and when you dequeue, size-- reduces the size.

Comment: *"I know it is not set automatically"* And how do you know what? Or why do you think that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default value is `0` for `int`.

And `size++` and `size--` is doing the changes to its value.

For more information refer: [Assignment, Arithmetic, and Unary Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)

Answer (score 2):

`size++` is equal to the statement `size = size + 1`, the same for `size--` which does `size = size - 1`

Answer (score 0):

All *instance variables* will be assigned a *default* value by the compiler if you haven't provided one.
Snippet from [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> Default value will be zero or null depending the data types.

The link also has a grid which tells you about the default values for all data types.

Local variables are variables which are used inside a method:

> The compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local 
>   variable. If you cannot initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error.

Comment: You might want to read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text